# Spring Boot and OAuth2: redirect url over reverse proxy

Tags: java, apache, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

Good day.

I'm developing a spring-boot service which runs under certain port, let's say hostname:8080 in server. Users access this service over apache proxy, url.com/application

Now apache is configured:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost Off
ProxyPass /application http://hostname:8080
ProxyPassReverse /application http://hostname:8080
```

I use oauth2 for authentication and authentication happens in authserver.com

Application.yml:

```
 oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: username
      clientSecret: 123123
      accessTokenUri: http://authserver.com/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://authserver.com/oauth/authorize
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://authserver.com/oauth/user
      preferTokenInfo: false
```

1. I request url.com/application
2. I get redirected to form based authentication authserver.com/oath/authorize?client_id=username&redirect_url=url.com/login&...
3. Once authenticated I get redirected back to url.com/login which was given as GET parameter in previous step. This is resulted to 404.

How can I modify that redirect_url in Spring Boot config? It should be url.com/application/login.

pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.M2</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependecies>
```

Security config:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public static class WebSecurityConfig extends OAuth2SsoConfiguration {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/health", "/status", "/ws", "/ws/*", "/mappings", "/beans")
                .anonymous();
        http.csrf().disable();
        super.configure(http);
    }

}
```

Using Spring Cloud Security 1.0.0.RC3

Comment: As an aside, have you considered using AJP to proxy to your (embedded?) Tomcat web app? That helps in getting the headers and path rewrites setup correctly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30095615/53444

Comment: Thanks! It seems that using remote ip valve tomcat configuration could solve my problem.

Comment: Might not need the class anymore: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-tomcat-behind-a-proxy-server

Comment: how can I disable userAuthentication redirection in this application?

Comment: Incase someone came here looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57557022/1581226)

Answer (score 3):

Please follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34290681/4587085) answer. It solved my day.

**1.** You have to setup the headers on your Apache proxy:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.myapp.org
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ... (SSL directives omitted for readability)
</VirtualHost>
```

**2.** You have to tell your Spring Boot app to use these headers. So put the following line in your application.properties (or any other place where Spring Boots understands properties):

```
server.use-forward-headers=true
```

Answer (score 0):

From the OAuth2 spec:

> 3.1.2.  Redirection Endpoint
>
> After completing its interaction with the resource owner, the
>      authorization server directs the resource owner's user-agent back to
>      the client.  The authorization server redirects the user-agent to the
>      client's redirection endpoint previously established with the
>      authorization server during the client registration process or when
>      making the authorization request.
>
> The redirection endpoint URI MUST be an absolute URI as defined by
>      [RFC3986] Section 4.3.  The endpoint URI MAY include an
>      "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" formatted (per Appendix B) query
>      component ([RFC3986] Section 3.4), which MUST be retained when adding
>      additional query parameters.  The endpoint URI MUST NOT include a
>      fragment component.

there are 2 options how to handle redirection

- First, during the client registration the redirect url is stored in database
- Second, during requesting the authorization we can pass the redirect_url

I can see that you are using the second option by passing the redirect_url to the OAuth server `authserver.com/oath/authorize?client_id=username&redirect_url=url.com/login`

But the one who trigger this redirection is the `url.com/application`. Therefore you need to change/configure the `url.com/application` to redirect the request to `authserver.com/oath/authorize?client_id=username&redirect_url=url.com/application/login`.

If you are using spring security in your `url.com/application`, change the login page configuration url.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("authserver.com/oath/authorize?client_id=username&redirect_url=url.com/application/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();
}
```

Since your are not showing your application code the above code may or may not work.

Comment: Yes. My question was how to change/configure this in Spring Boot config.

Comment: can you put your spring security configuration here?

Comment: Thanks! Added security config.

Comment: spring will redirect the request to its original url that was blocked by login page. Can you try to access url.com/application/login first and see where the redirect url point to after authenticated?

Comment: how can I disable userAuthentication redirection in this application?